# log4j 1.x : detect if no config file given and programmatically set it up

Tags: java, logging, log4j, default

(If your using log4j version 2 this is not applicable)

Know how to set log4j to print debug and how to pro grammatically construct a default Properties object.

Want help with code to detect if log4j did not find a config file in classpath.

This for the times when don't have a log4j.xml to at least see all logs in console.

Code I have:

```
private static void log4Default() {
        boolean noLog = true;
  //how to set this to false if log4j did find a config file
//      File log4f = new File("log4j.xml");
//      File log4f2 = new File("log4j.properties");
//      
//      if(log4f.exists() || log4f2.exists()) {
//          noLog = false;
//      }else {
//          log4f = new File("target/classes/log4j.xml");
//          log4f2 = new File("target/classes/log4j.properties");
//          if(log4f.exists() || log4f2.exists()) {
//              noLog = false;
//          }
//      }
//      if(noLog) {
//          log4f = new File("target/test-classes/log4j.xml");
//          log4f2 = new File("target/test-classes/log4j.properties");
//          if(log4f.exists() || log4f2.exists()) {
//              noLog = false;
//          }
//      }

        if(noLog) {
            System.out.println("no log4j config, using default");
            Layout layout = new PatternLayout(" %-5p %t %d [%t][%F:%L] : %m%n");
            Appender ap = new ConsoleAppender(layout , ConsoleAppender.SYSTEM_OUT);
            Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.ALL);
            //Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new ConsoleAppender(layout, ConsoleAppender.SYSTEM_ERR));
            Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(ap);
        }

    }
```

Commented out the file exists as there could be an over ride and above is not foul proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this to check whether there is any `log4j.xml/.properties` file present in the classpath:

```
public void checkForLog4jConfigFile() {

org.apache.log4j.Logger rootLogger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getRootLogger();
Enumeration appenders = rootLogger.getAllAppenders();
if (!appenders.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println("LOG4J config file is missing");
} else {
    System.out.println("appender found "
    + ((Appender) appenders.nextElement()).getName());
}
}
```

Comment: thanks, so basically no appenders are added by default. i thought there might be a do nothing one.

Comment: I found this VERY useful -- I can configure the logger in testing code, and the default settings module now uses this method and only calls the Configurator if Not Already set.  As you realise I'd like more logging during testing :-)